# SWIGTYPE_p_p_ : a Pointer on a Pointer on a Structure ( From C/C++ to Java )

Tags: java, c++, pointers, java-native-interface, swig

I'm using Swig to generate Java classes.

I need to deal with a **pointer on a pointer on a structure**.

I have this structure :

```
struct Model {
    uint32_t serial;    
}
```

And I have a function in the C/C++ that needs to be wrapped :

```
void getModel( Model ** model ){
   // instructions...
}
```

I get as a result this Java class :

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_p_Model {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_p_Model(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_p_Model() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_p_Model obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

So my questions are :

1. how can I use this class?
2. How can I make a `typemap` in Swig to get read of `SWIGTYPE_p_p` ?

Comment: There is no pointer to pointer in java so you have to ask what is the semantics of the function? It looks like it is expecting to get the address of a pointer to Model so it can set the pointer to an existing Model instance? You shouldn't need typemap, just need to figure out the right wrapper.