# C/C++ : Pointer on Pointer on structure

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I have 2 structures :

```
struct A {
  int m1;
  int m2;
}
```

and the second struct which has as a member the previous struct :

```
struct Temp_A {    
  A a;    
}
```

Then I have in my program :

```
Temp_A** temp_a;
```

So my questions are :

1. How can I allocate memory for `temp_a` ?
2. How can I access to `a`? It should be something kind of (*temp_a)->a...

Thank you!

Comment: Really rather similar to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932242/swigtype-p-p-a-pointer-on-a-pointer-on-a-structure-from-c-c-to-java

Comment: The answers for both questions depends on how you are supposed to use `temp_a`. What is your use case? What is the purpose of the design? And most importantly, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, yes you're right, but I worry that the other question of mine won't receive any answer due to the JNI context...

Comment: As a side-note, since you tagged your question C++, why not use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I allocate memory for temp_a ?

```
//1 here is number of pointer elements you want as temp_a is pointer to pointer 
// or for simplicity array of pointers.
temp_a = malloc(sizeof(*temp_a)* 1); 

//then you should allocate temp_a[0] too
temp_a[0] = malloc(sizeof(**temp_a));
```

> How can I access to a

```
(*temp_a)->a
//and tehn
(*temp_a)->a.m1

//you can access as too
temp_a[0]->a
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to declare `Temp_A` as follow:

```
struct Temp_A {    
  struct A a;    
}
```

Now, `Temp_A**` points to a pointer to `Temp_A`, so you can assign like

```
temp_a = malloc(sizeof(Temp_A*));
(*temp_a) = malloc(sizeof(Temp_A));
```

You can access like

```
(*temp_a)->a
```